# How to find if a specific letter is a part of a word, and how to get its index?

Tags: python, recursion, indexing

I need to write a function which gets a word and a letter and gives as an output the index of the first appearance of the letter in the word.

running examples :

```
char_first_index("aabcb","b") #would output 2

char_first_index("","x") #would output None
```

I'm supposed to do this using recursion, but I can't figure out how to find the index of the letter using recursion, while using loops it would be much easier.

Please, explain how can I count using recursion, and how can I find the index.
This is my code:

```
def char_first_index(s,c):
if s=="":
    return None
if s[0]==c:
    return 0
else:
    s=s[1:]
    return char_first_index(s,c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about it - in your second case, you *always* `return 0`. You need instead to keep track of how many characters you've had already, i.e. how many recursions:

```
def char_first_index(s, c):
    if not s:
        return None
    elif s[0] == c:
        return 0
    else:
        index = char_first_index(s[1:], c)
        if index is not None:
            return index + 1
```